# Crystal Report show history based only on two field changes

Tags: crystal-reports, report

I’m trying to write a report using the history_table. 
I want to know how would I only bring the records only to show a history if only two fields have changed ex (ss.dem1) and (ss.dem2) in the table
If anything else changes like phone or address that are in the table as well to not bring that up or suppress it in the report. I want to see the data only those 2 fields have changed and every time it has changed as a history.
[image]

This would be an example of what I'm trying to accomplish.

I also used tried to use a suppression formula but only gave me the last record and not show me the example like I would of like above

not onlastrecord and next(PATID)=PATID and next(ssdem1)=ssdem1
or
not onlastrecord and next(PATID)=PATID and next(ssdem2)=ssdem2

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the primary key in your history table? Is there a date/time field where the changes took place?

Comment: Yes there is a date/time field in the table I also Tried using a suppression formula but seem not to work properly                 not onlastrecord and next(PATID)=PATID and next(ssdem1)=ssdem1
or
not onlastrecord and next(PATID)=PATID and next(ssdem2)=ssdem2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the DB side you could do a self-join and only keep the records where one of those items you're interested in has changed, ex:

```
select WHATEVER
from HISTORY H1, HISTORY H2
where H1.PAT_ID=H2.PAT_ID
 and (H1.DEM1 <> H2.DEM1
      or H1.DEM2 <> H2.DEM2
      etc...)
```

Or, you could order the report by PAT_ID, then by the date/time of the edit and then suppress the rows where nothing changes, which sounds like what you were trying to do. If you post the exact suppression formula I might be able to see where you were going wrong. Should be something like:

```
not(onfirstrecord) or
({TABLE.PAT_ID}=previous({TABLE.PAT_ID})
 and {TABLE.DEM1}=previous({TABLE.DEM1}) //check all fields you're concerned with for equality
 and {TABLE.DEM2=previous({TABLE.DEM2})
 and etc...)
```

Comment: not onlastrecord and next(PATID)=PATID and next(ssdem1)=ssdem1
or
not onlastrecord and next(PATID)=PATID and next(ssdem2)=ssdem2

Comment: @Dagz200 Try forming your formula as I have above. There are a couple problems with your logic here. For one, that will suppress when *either*, not *both* ssdem1 or ssdem2 are the same between records. Two, there is no reason that your last record could not be a duplicate.

Comment: @ Ryan Thanks for the help that worked. I need to modify it a bit to also take the " No Value" as well.